# How to assign alternative depth values only to the child nodes in d3js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, d3.js

Right Now the all nodes have fixed depth. How can I assign an alternative value only to the child nodes

[image: see graph]

I tried to change values `nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 200; });` but it effects all the nodes. I want output like this:

[image: this]

Comment: Please add code samples. Maybe is also better you don't link all of your text, but add a link at the end of each sentence, so your question is clearly formatted

Comment: i meant you should format your post such as

Right Now the all nodes have fixed depth.How can i assign an alternative values only to the child nodes [see screenshot]

 I tried to change values nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 200; }); but it effects all the nodes. I want output like this [see screenshot]

I.E. detach your text and give a separate plase for the links you put

Comment: Should only the children of the last parent be variate along Y ? Like in a Odd-Even sequence ?

Comment: @ThirueswaranRajagopalan yes i want it that way.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/b2rd7ps8/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `d.depth` to filter the value :

```
nodes.forEach(function(d) { 
    // value of y differ if d.depth === 1
    d.y = d.depth === 1 ? d.depth * maxLabel : d.depth * 200;
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/zmozdpum/

Note : if you want to have different size for odd nodes, have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmozdpum/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/b2rd7ps8/1/

```
function normalizeNodesDepth(node){
    /* get index of parent from it's parent's children array..*/
    var parentIndex = (!!node.parent && node.parent != 'null' && !!node.parent.parent && node.parent.parent != 'null' ) ? node.parent.parent.children.map(e => e.id).indexOf(node.parent.id) : null;
    /* if node is the last child and it's parent index is even, mutiple by greater ...*/
    node.y = node.depth * maxLabel * ((parentIndex != null && !(parentIndex % 2) && (!node.children || !!node.children.length)) ? 1.5 : 1);

    if(!node.children) { return; }

    /* recur for all its children ...*/
    node.children.forEach((child, index) => {
        normalizeNodesDepth(child);
    });
}     

 //nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * maxLabel; });
 normalizeNodesDepth(root);
```